# Flexslider rtl swipe direction issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, flexslider

I am using the flexslider with rtl support provided by [rtl-this.com](http://rtl-this.com/sites/default/files/demos/FlexSlider/demo/basic-rtl.html).

When swiping the slider in touch screens, it moves in the opposite direction.

What fix can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed in the latest version:
https://github.com/layalk/FlexSlider/tree/rtl
Now it works with `rtl:true`

`dx` is multiplied by -1 if in `rtl` mode.

```
dx = (vertical) ? startX - localY : (slider.vars.rtl?-1:1)*(startX - localX);
```

Which makes the `target` gets picked correctly.
It also applies the changes for `msGesture` is true.

Answer (score -1):

Added `rtl: false` in js.

Edited two lines in js

`slider.setProps(offset + dx, "setTouch");` changed to

`slider.setProps(offset - dx, "setTouch");`

`target = (updateDx > 0) ? slider.getTarget('next') : slider.getTarget('prev');` changed to -

`target = (updateDx > 0) ? slider.getTarget('prev') : slider.getTarget('next');`

This solved the issue.